# I am not able to open open-in-jd-gui.sh in my ubuntu terminal.how to use the open-in-jd-gui.sh tar file

Tags: java, eclipse, decompiler

**i want to open open-in-jd-gui.sh this file in ubuntu terminal or execute in eclipse.i have some java class files.but in windows i know that.but in ubuntu how to excute this file.
how to execute the jd-gui-0.3.3linuxi686.tar.gz in ubuntu terminal

Comment: If jd-gui just doesn't open on Ubuntu you might need to install these libs: `sudo apt-get install ia32-libs-gtk`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the extracted directory (jd-gui-0.3.3.linux.i686) there should be a bin file called **jd-gui** .Run it from terminal.

Comment: here i have only one file called open-in-jd-gui.sh.how to use it

Comment: that is not the right file i think.down load it form [link](http://java.decompiler.free.fr/jd-gui/downloads/jd-gui-0.3.3.linux.i686.tar.gz) check md5sum for *64491556a81f65b8ad58ef44c5ec99c0*

Comment: i got the source file of java class file using this java decompiler.but at the same time how to open the xml file

Comment: i decompile the source code .but i couldnt open the manifest file

Comment: @rajesh open jar file itself, you can see the entire tree.By exploring you can get the manifest file also.

Comment: no.here the jar file  decompile the source file only.i couldnt see the manifest file.only the classes.dex file is extracted and decompiled as a source file.i cant get xml and manifest file

Comment: yes.i am also using the same version.i think i dont know how to extract app file.but i am using this comment cd /Desktop/dex2.jar/d2j-dex2jar.sh classes.dex.here i got only java files..

Comment: where did u get this?i need this jar file.can u show the link?

Comment: How to get this file jar xf XXX.jar

Comment: jar xf xxx.jar is not a file.**jar** is a command **xf** are options , go to the directory where jar is located and say command jar xf jar_to_extract.jar.jar will get extracted and look for the required files.For your info [link](http://java.sun.com/developer/Books/javaprogramming/JAR/basics/unpack.html)

Comment: I clicked JAVA Decompiler--->open the path--> where i locate my app source file.it shows only java file type.not manifest file

Comment: when i open the manifest file i got like this Manifest-Version: 1.0
Created-By: 1.0 (Android)

Name: res/drawable/frame_small.9.png
SHA1-Digest: IXC1koDB+kFUEFAbuHrZHUHnIks=

Name: res/drawable-hdpi-v4/widget_led_purple_on.png
SHA1-Digest: Bt1li/NuXppOGFZWOYO96uKxAQ8=

Name: res/drawable/w_settings_icon.png
SHA1-Digest: fpXVUx4GDhhUu3MSz20I/2VSipo=

Name: res/drawable/w_led_disclaimer.png
SHA1-Digest: sOgEdOh79A5PzMJraDf/IjIG3yE=

Comment: i didnt get the main activity name and other contents missing

Comment: @rajesh even I don't have much idea about manifest file .That might be the default one.Better explained here [link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/defman.html).If you have still clarifications better post it as a new one(if it is worth..) .Bcz stack overflow is showing here it as a extended discussion :)